# jqmodal, trying to display modal on click with text from php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jqmodal

First time user of jqmodal here and I am trying to display a modal when I click a button.  However, the text that I want to put on the modal is in a php file, which is in the href attribute.  How can I get the information in the php file to the modal when I click this button?

I am completely lost here, any help would be great.

Let's say:

```
 .json (button) 

 /folder/file.php (php file)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples
example 2

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I overlooked that.